# Is there a bug in GCC 4.7.2's implementation of shared_ptr's (templated) assignment operator?

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, c++11, smart-pointers

My question concerns the implementation of `shared_ptr`'s assignment operator template in GCC 4.7.2, which I suspect to contain a bug.

**PREMISE 1: C++11 STANDARD**

Here is the signature of the assignment operator template I am talking about:

```
template<class Y> shared_ptr& operator=(const shared_ptr<Y>& r) noexcept;
```

From the C++11 Standard (20.7.2.2.3):

*"Equivalent to* `shared_ptr(r).swap(*this)`*."*

In other words, the assignment operator template is defined in terms of constructor template. The signature of the constructor template is as follows:

```
template<class Y> shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<Y>& r) noexcept;
```

From the C++11 Standard (20.7.2.2.1):

*"Requires: The [...] constructor shall not participate in the overload resolution unless Y* is implicitly convertible to T*."*

**PREMISE 2: GCC 4.7.2's IMPLEMENTATION:**

Now GCC 4.7.2's implementation of the constructor template seems correct to me (`std::__shared_ptr` is a base class of `std::shared_ptr`):

```
template<typename _Tp1, typename = 
typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<_Tp1*, _Tp*>::value>::type>
__shared_ptr(__shared_ptr<_Tp1, _Lp>&& __r) noexcept
    : 
    _M_ptr(__r._M_ptr), 
    _M_refcount()
{
    _M_refcount._M_swap(__r._M_refcount);
    __r._M_ptr = 0;
}
```

However, GCC 4.7.2's implementation of the assignment operator template is the following:

```
template<typename _Tp1>
__shared_ptr& operator=(const __shared_ptr<_Tp1, _Lp>& __r) noexcept
{
    _M_ptr = __r._M_ptr;
    _M_refcount = __r._M_refcount; // __shared_count::op= doesn't throw
    return *this;
}
```

What strikes me is that this operation is **not** defined in terms of the constructor template, nor of `swap()`. In particular, the plain assignment `_M_ptr = __r._M_ptr` does not yield the same result as when the types `_Tp1*` and `_Tp*` are explicitly checked for convertibility through `std::is_convertible` (*which can be specialized*).

**PREMISE 3: VC10 IMPLEMENTATION**

I noticed that VC10 does have a more conforming implementation in this respect, which I consider to be correct and behaves as I expected in my test cases (while GCC's doesn't):

```
template<class _Ty2>
_Myt& operator=(const shared_ptr<_Ty2>& _Right)
{
    // assign shared ownership of resource owned by _Right
    shared_ptr(_Right).swap(*this);
    return (*this);
}
```

**QUESTION**:

Is there indeed a bug in GCC 4.7.2's implementation of `shared_ptr`? I could not find any bug report for this issue.

**POST SCRIPTUM**:

If you wish to ask me what my test cases are, *why* do I care about this seemingly unimportant detail and why do I seem to imply that I need to specialize `std::is_convertible`, please do so in chat. It is a long story and there's no way of summing it up without being misunderstood (with all of its unpleasant consequences). Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you've got the wrong constructor template there, you've given the one that converts from a different raw pointer, not the one that converts from a different `shared_ptr`

Comment: Even though you can specialize `is_convertible`, you must not do so unless you maintain the behaviour required by the standard...

Comment: @JonathanWakely: you're right, sorry. I will edit my question

Comment: [meta.type.synop]/1 _"The behavior of a program that adds specializations for any of the class templates defined in this subclause is undefined unless otherwise specified."_  Do you have a testcase that isn't undefined and behaves differently for GCC's and MSVC's implementations? IIRC I copied that assignment operator code straight from Boost.

Comment: @AndyProwl: If you don't want people to ask about your test cases, you shouldn't include any reference to them in the question... That said, I think it would work as a community wiki answer, which in my mind are supplimentary additionals to other answers or the question. But that's just me. The reason it's improtant is that you're claiming defect based off these tests; we need to check if your tests are defective.

Comment: @KerrekSB, you must not do so, full stop.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Oh OK, even better!

Comment: @JonathanWakely: great reference, thank you! But letting alone my (wrong) idea of specializing `std::is_convertible`, does that make GCC's implementation conforming?

Comment: I'm writing an answer, hang on :)

Comment: Even if specializing `std::is_convertible` is okay, I don't think that would change the meaning of the phrase "`Y*` is implicitly convertible to `T*`".

Comment: @GManNickG: I see what you mean. You have a point.

Comment: I am curious as of your `is_convertible` requirements. Note that the standard does not require `std::is_convertible<T,U>::value`, but rather that they are convertible, and that is implicitly checked in the assignment. Providing specializations of `is_convertible` can only limit the use, as the initialization/assignment still needs to take place in the cases where the test passes. Also note that the standard does not require the use of SFINAE or the use of `std::is_convertible` so depending on that behavior makes your program non-portable.

Comment: @aschepler: I think JonathanWakely proved that it is not okay to specialize `std::is_convertible`. Actually there is an "unless otherwise specified" which makes me wonder if there are cases where this is possible.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I understand, but whatever you rely on, the standard mandates the behavior of operator = to be the same as constructor + swap. This is what I am questioning: is it the case for GCC's implementation? It obviously is for VC10's

Comment: @AndyProwl C++ has a general "as if" rule: if bits are not implemented as specified in the standard, but behave "as if" they were -- meaning a correct program cannot tell that they're implemented differently -- it's not a bug in the implementation. That's why the question of whether you can see different behaviour in a program that has defined behaviour is very relevant.

Comment: @AndyProwl: [Chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22411/room-for-gmannickg-and-andy-prowl) for others and myself to see your tests. :)

Comment: @hvd: I understand, but the standard does mandate that operator = is exactly the same as constructor + swap. Now if constructor + swap is implemented by using `std::is_convertible` and `operator =` is implemented another way, I would like to figure out if the two implementations are equivalent

Comment: @AndyProwl: No, the standard mandates that the behavior of `operator=` is the same as that required for *constructor+swap* **in** the standard.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> What strikes me is that this operation is **not** defined in terms of the constructor template, nor of `swap()`.

It doesn't need to be, it only needs to behave *as if* it was defined in those terms.

> In particular, the plain assignment `_M_ptr = __r._M_ptr` does not yield the same result as when the types `_Tp1*` and `_Tp*` are explicitly checked for convertibility through `std::is_convertible` (*which can be specialized*).

I disagree: **[meta.type.synop]/1** *The behavior of a program that adds specializations for any of the class templates defined in this subclause is undefined unless otherwise specified.*

So you can't change the meaning of `is_convertible<Y*, T*>` and if `Y*` is convertible to `T*` then the assignment will work and since both assignments (of the pointer and the refcount object) are `noexcept` the end result is equivalent to the swap.  If the pointers are not convertible then the assignment will fail to compile, but so would `shared_ptr(r).swap(*this)`, so it's still equivalent.

If I'm wrong then please file a bug report and I'll fix it, but I don't think a conforming program can detect the difference between the libstdc++ implementation and the requirements of the standard.  That said, I wouldn't have any objections to changing it to be implemented in terms of `swap`. The current implementation came straight from the `shared_ptr` in [Boost 1.32](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/tags/release/Boost_1_32_0/boost/boost/shared_ptr.hpp), I don't know if Boost still does it the same way or if it uses `shared_ptr(r).swap(*this)` now.

[Full disclosure, I'm a libstdc++ maintainer and mostly responsible for the `shared_ptr` code, which was originally kindly donated by the authors of `boost::shared_ptr` and then mutiliated by me since then.]

Comment: The current version of Boost (1.52.0) does implement it as `this_type(r).swap(*this);`. I know this implementation is there since at least version 1.44.0. Not sure when this has been changed.

Answer (score 6):

The implementation in GCC conforms with the requirements in the standard. When the standard defines that the behavior of one function is equivalent to a different set of functions it means that the effect of the former is equivalent to the effect of the latter functions as defined in the standard (rather than as implemented).

The standard does not require the use of  `std::is_convertible` for that constructor. It requires SFINAE for the constructor, but it does not require SFINAE for the assignment operator. The requirement that the types are convertible are placed on the program, not on the implementation of the `std::shared_ptr` and it is your responsibility. If the types passed in are not convertible, then it is a bug in your program. If they are then the implementation must accept the code even if you wanted to disable the use by specializing the `is_convertible` template.

Then again, specializing `is_convertible` to limit the conversions of **pointers** is undefined behavior, as you are changing the semantics of the base template, which is explicitly disallowed in the standard.

This leads to the original question that you don't want to answer: what is the use case that made you think on this solution. Or said otherwise, why do people keep on asking about solutions rather than about the real problems they want solved?

Comment: It **does** require SFINAE for that constructor: [util.smartptr.shared.const]/17 _The second constructor shall not participate in the overload resolution unless `Y*` is implicitly
convertible to `T*`._  But it doesn't require SFINAE for the assignment operator, so it's irrelevant.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: You are correct, I looked at the wrong constructor.